# hook_user_login being called twice?

Tags: 7, hooks, users

I'm storing the session details from Drupal to share with another system, so users don't have to log in twice for each system.

It appears that my `hook_user_login` is being called twice.  Right now I'm just calling:

```
mymodule_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  debug(session_id());
}
```

to see if the session I'm storing is the same as the session being used.

I'm getting the debug statement twice, with two different `session_id` values.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you sure there is just a logged-in user when you are executing that code?

Comment: Yes, it's my own dev machine, and I'm the only one connected, and the only one with the test credentials.  I am authenticating against my own user db however, but I can't see how that would trigger two login hooks

Comment: If you are already logged in when executing that code, and there isn't code that impersonates another user, that hook should not be more than once. It is rather difficult to say what it is going on, though.

Comment: I'm starting from anonymous, and then logging in.  Is the anonymous session playing somehow in this?

Comment: the session_name() isn't changing, just the session_id().  Does calling session_id() change its value?

Comment: I tried saving data in the session, logging in and out, with a custom module that implements `hook_user_login()` (and calling `session_id()`) installed on my test site, but I could not get that hook to be called twice; it is just called when the current user is an authenticated user.

Comment: Just curious, are you using `user_external_login_register`? Adding that to the login form validation can trigger two login events.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not an answer (I don't yet have enough reputation to post a comment); I am also uncertain if you are still looking for answer. It is possible sometimes for distributed modules to call `user_login_submit`.

For example, the D7 LDAP module's `_ldap_authentication_user_login_authenticate_validate` calls `user_login_submit`, which causes the user login form to fork two calls to `user_login_finalize`, both of which triggers `hook_user_login`. If you are still experiencing this problem, one possible way to debug your application is to use PHP XDebug, and `dsm` function traces.

After you have installed [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/download.php), you can use `xdebug_call_function()` on `user_login_submit`, `user_login_finalize`, `user_module_invoke` to see where the two calls of `hook_user_login` are coming from. I hope this helps.